# Easiest way to mass change lead ownership based on a report

Tags: reporting, leads, record-owner, lead-owner

I have a report of about 300 leads that need to have the lead owner replaced. Half of the leads need to go to one person, and the other half to another. Currently I have been exporting the report into an excel file, adding the lead owner's Id to the person owner field, and using workbench to update. I have tried creating a lead view as well, but I can't figure out how to do that based on a report. I'm sure there is a more simple way.

Can someone let me know the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks,
Rahim

Comment: Hi, you are having some data to change, but please export this report into CSV file format not into Excel. Please let me know if it is solving your problem.

Comment: You can follow another admin approach to use transfer records, apply the same criteria that you have in your reports. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325944&type=1